# Generate combinations of values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns. I need to generate `combinations` (**always in 3's**) of the values (in "tests"column) of the table that were performed based on a particular `"diagnosis"`. With reference to the table below, for each `cust_id` there is a `"diagnosis"` column based on which the `"tests"` were performed. Now for every diagnosis value group, I need to generate unique combinations of the corresponding values in the "tests" column. Note, the combinations should always be with 3 values.

PATIENT:

```
pat_id | diagnosis | tests

1001 | Thyroid | CAT
1001 | Thyroid | MRI
1001 | Thyroid | Blood

1001 | Tonsil  | CAT
1001 | Tonsil  | MRI
1001 | Tonsil  | Blood
1001 | Tonsil  | RAPID

1002 | Pneumonia | MRI
1002 | Pneumonia | Eliza
```

so, for `pat_id = '1001'` and `diagnosis = 'Thyroid'` we see that "tests" have 3 distinct values. Hence, only **1** unique combination is possible i.e. `{CAT, MRI, Blood}`.
Similarly, for `pat_id = '1001'` and `diagnosis = 'Tonsil'`, we see there are 4 distinct values in "test" column. Hence, there will be 4 combinations i.e. `{CAT, MRI, Blood}`, `{CAT, MRI, RAPID}`, `{MRI, Blood, RAPID}` & `{CAT, blood, RAPID}`.
For `pat_id = '1002'` only two unique values exists. Hence the combination will be only 1 i.e. `{MRI, Eliza}`
Like this, I need to generate similar combinations for all diagnosis values in a group and output the unique combination that occurs the max number of times than the other combinations in that table.

Note that combinations should be made with 3 values at any time.

There are about `25 Mil` records in this table. So is there any way to effectively implement  this in **MySQL** without major performance impact ?

PS: If required we have a python environment which could be leveraged for implementing this if required by reading the data from a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join:

```
select p1.pat_id, p1.diagnosis, p1.tests, p2.tests, p3.tests
from patient p1 join
     patient p2
     on p1.pat_id = p2.pat_id and p1.diagnosis = p2.diagnosis and
        p1.tests < p2.tests join
     patient p3
     on p2.pat_id = p3.pat_id and p2.diagnosis = p3.diagnosis and
        p2.tests < p3.tests ;
```

Even with the recommended index on `(pat_id, diagnosis, tests)`, this will be slow because of the volume of data that the query will produce.

Comment: The solution does not output the pat_id = '1002' which has only 2 unique values. The logic must also handle instances where there are less than 3 unique values. The output needs to show {MRI, ELIZA} for diagnosis = Pneumonia. Also, could you please indicate how to discern which combination has occurred the most in the table.

Comment: @marie20 . . . That would be a different question.  You explicitly state:  "Note, the combinations should always be with 3 values."  If you want empty values *when there are not three* then use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. The requirement also requires that in case there are less than 3 tests, that should also show in the output with empty/Null value in the 3rd position For e.g. pat_id = 1002 -> {MRI, Eliza}. I tried using the Left Join but couldn't get that to work. Could you please help ? Also, how do i derive which combination occurs the most in the data-set ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @marie20 . . . *New* questions should be asked as *new* questions, not in comments.  If you have a question about the most common combinations, then ask it as a question.

Comment: i had mentioned these requirement in this question already the first time i had submitted it. Please refer to the paragraph following the table sample data. I'd still create a new question if it is still required. Pls let me know.